# How to make selection on a single checkbox of a checkbox list?

Tags: c#, asp.net

On my web application I am using a checkbox list .I am binding this Checkbox list using a datatable like

```
cblMenuAccess.DataTextField = "Role_Name";
cblMenuAccess.DataValueField = "Role_Code";
cblMenuAccess.DataBind();
```

and now I am trying to make some checkbox checked from C# code.Its not working as expected.
This is i did so far

```
foreach (DataRow row1 in dt2.Rows)
{
    string Role_Code = row1["User_Role_Code"].ToString();
    foreach (ListItem oItem in cblMenuAccess.Items)
    {
        if (oItem.Value == Role_Code)
        {
            //oItem.Value need to be checked true 
        }
    }
}
```

Do anyone know how to make this checkbox checked with respect to its value ??

Comment: `Its not working as expected.` What did you expect? What did it do instead?

Comment: @mjwills i tried using a for loop and tried to make `cblMenuAccess[i]` true ..and it was also syntax error.. !! how can i make that checkbox true ??

Answer (score 0):

i give you simple example of checkboxlist

```
Select Fruit:
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkFruits" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Apple" Value="1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Mango" Value="2" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Papaya" Value="3" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Banana" Value="4" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Orange" Value="5" />
</asp:CheckBoxList>
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick = "Submit" />


protected void Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string message = "";
    foreach (ListItem item in chkFruits.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            message += "Value: " + item.Value;
            message += " Text: " + item.Text;
            message += "\\n";
        }
    }

    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + message + "');", true);
}
```

Comment: am not trying to take value here.. i am trying to make the selection using C# code..!! From your example, i need to check the value="5" on form load.

Comment: you simply use  cblMenuAccess.DataTextField = "Role_Name";
cblMenuAccess.DataValueField = "Role_Code";
cblMenuAccess.DataBind();